# login view controller and main tab bar controller

Tags: ios, presentviewcontroller

I have an app that should either show a login page or a main tab bar controller.

What's the best way to set this up? For now I'm starting out with an empty view controller and then either presenting a navigation controller for the login flow, or a tab bar controller for the main app. This means the entire contents of my app live within a modally presented view. Is that bad?

How do most people handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume most people set the tab bar as their default view and present a modal login controller above it if necessary. Then when you log in you can just dismiss the login controller and you are back at your tab bar controller.

Your method should work just fine though.